# Microsoft Drivers 3.0 for PHP for SQL Server

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, pdo, windows-server-2003

I have installed on my Microsoft Windows Server 2012 x64 the Microsoft Drivers 3.0 for PHP for SQL Server

I have configured PHP 5.4 to load the driver, I need it to use PDO with Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2, installed on a different machine.

When I try to perform a connection to my SQL server using PDO on PHP I get this error:

> This extension requires the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client
>   ODBC Driver to communicate with SQL Server. Access the following URL
>   to download the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client ODBC driver
>   for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712

Looking in the system requirements of Microsoft Drivers 3.0 for PHP for SQL Server I read:

- Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client available in the SQL Server 2012 Feature Pack.
- Any edition of SQL Server 2005 or later.

Does it mean that I need to install the entire MSQL server on my machine even if I use a different machine to run the MSQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It requires just the SQL Server 2012 Native Client, not the SQL Server 2005 or later.

Thanks Microsoft for the crappy documentation.